# What are the opportunities for moving into Space Science & Exploration for Software Engineer

Tags: career, astronaut-recruitment

I am a `Computer Science Engineer` with *3 years* working as a `Software Developer` from India.

**Space Exploration** and its knowledge draws my attention greatlyy and I am very much keen to know more and be a part of system where I can explore and indulge completely in it.

> Please tell me the paths like where I can **apply** to or what are the
>   **opportunities** present for me globally.

Comment: I think the answer is probably sad.

Comment: Its reason is that these are very liked positions even between people with a more related academical papers (for example, aviation engineer). They are also native speakers of the country (typically, English). They have also far more possibilities for different security clearances which are required for classified things. And there are few jobs, but many candidates. But I won't demoralize you! You may have luck. Most likely you won't start as the chief engineer of the SpaceX.

Comment: @peterh Can you elaborate more in the answer?

Comment: Related questions: https://space.stackexchange.com/q/25236/4660, https://space.stackexchange.com/q/4311/4660

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried looking at [ISRO's career page](https://www.isro.gov.in/careers)?

It looks like they regularly recruit computer scientists.  Answers keys for one of the recent testings rounds were posted April 22 2018.  So watch for the next round and give it a shot?

Comment: I am working as a Web developer and the Programming Languages that I use I daily life is PHP and Nodejs. Do I need to learn Python as well? Any comment on this.

Comment: Given that the ISRO website tells you you're going to a link outside the website when you're clearly not (e.g. clicking on any of the job posting links), somebody who knows about web dev couldn't hurt.

Comment: @MohdBelal everyone should always learn Python ;-) How are things going? I noticed that a question somewhat similar to yours [Transitioning into space software engineering](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/25236/12102) has several helpful answers. The question was written in a more specific way and so it seems it was felt to be answerable with specific answers. If you would like to re-open your question, consider rewriting it and clicking `re-open` if you see it, or ping me or someone for assistance.

Answer (score 2):

Ironically, I moved from the Aerospace industry into software/technology product space primarily because there were more jobs, more opportunity to create/join start-ups and the diversity of opportunities from a sector perspective.  If you are a skilled software developer, there are MANY opportunities in defense sector - just look at Lockheed, etc. career pages. You'd likely need to find something in your own country as most jobs require security clearance of some level for nationals.  However, this should not prevent you from getting started in working with SW products, commercial or open-source, that the industry depends on.

Some things to look into:

1.) Research how to work with large data sets and make sense in trying to identify trends, predict fail modes, and study the types of data space companies collect.  SpaceX collects tons of data in a single flight!  What would they do with it, how would they analyze?  Learn which tools help you do that.  Knowing how to code, leverage APIs, get systems to talk to each other: All critical skills needed to support rocket scientists!

Check out things like..

- Big data:
  https://www.mongodb.com/scale/open-source-big-data-analytics
  Datasets: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets

2.) Computer modeling and sim: Computational fluid dynamics

Go check out Anderson, Tannehill and Pletcher CFD&HT texts on CFD to get the gist of the field, then play with os tools like...

- https://www.openfoam.com/products/visualcfd.php
  https://su2code.github.io/ - great for python advocates
  https://www.simscale.com/

I'd get started with those and figure out how you can help ISRO in Bangalore or any supporting contractors on national missions.